# Httpd on Centos6 not listing directory contents

Tags: configuration, httpd, file-permissions, selinux

I have a folder (which is NOT the conventional /var/www/html folder!) /Server/Websites/Default on my Centos6.4 server. There is only one file, phpinfo.php (with the obvious code in it). Running `http://localhost/Default/phpinfo.php` in firefox, shows the correct php info page. When I visit `http://localhost/Default/` page, it shows me a Forbidden 'You don't have permission to access / on this server.' page. I want it to list the directory contents.

In my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file, I have (too long to display, so Im pasting some key lines that I think matter):

```
DocumentRoot "/Server/Websites"
<Directory /Server/Websites>
    Options +Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

SELinux wise, I have also for `# getsebool -a | grep httpd`:

```
allow_httpd_anon_write --> off
allow_httpd_mod_auth_ntlm_winbind --> off
allow_httpd_mod_auth_pam --> off
allow_httpd_sys_script_anon_write --> off
httpd_builtin_scripting --> on
httpd_can_check_spam --> off
httpd_can_network_connect --> off
httpd_can_network_connect_cobbler --> off
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> off
httpd_can_network_memcache --> off
httpd_can_network_relay --> off
httpd_can_sendmail --> off
httpd_dbus_avahi --> on
httpd_enable_cgi --> on
httpd_enable_ftp_server --> off
httpd_enable_homedirs --> off
httpd_execmem --> off
httpd_manage_ipa --> off
httpd_read_user_content --> off
httpd_run_stickshift --> off
httpd_setrlimit --> off
httpd_ssi_exec --> off
httpd_tmp_exec --> off
httpd_tty_comm --> on
httpd_unified --> on
httpd_use_cifs --> off
httpd_use_fusefs --> off
httpd_use_gpg --> off
httpd_use_nfs --> off
httpd_use_openstack --> off
httpd_verify_dns --> off
```

And `# ls -lZ`:

```
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_rw_t:s0 Websites
```

What am I overseeing?

Comment: Can you please add the output of `ls -lZ /Server` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out you had to explicitly say Options +Indexes in the httpd config. Thank you all so much for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, verify the permissions of the directory /Server/Websites/Default. Does your Apache user (in RHEL/CentOS apache) has permissions to list the contect of the directory (at least r-x for this user)?

Secondly, try to verify whether SELinux is responsible. Try to temporarily enable permissive mode only with

```
setenforce 0
```

If it works now there may be a problem with context of your dirs/files. Re-enable enforcing mode with

```
setenforce 1
```

and relabel your new directory structure recursively with

```
chcon -R --reference=/var/www /Server/Websites
```

Does it help?

Comment: It wasn't quite the fault of selinux, see my own answer. I like the ease of how you would test selinux and how you copy labels accross. Thanks